# How to list Networks; a docker container is attached to using format template?

Tags: docker, go, go-templates

When I want to check a list of containers a bridge driver is connected to, I do the followings,

```
docker network inspect br01 --format='{{range .Containers}}{{println .Name}}{{end}}'
```

Which gives the following output,

```
network-test01
network-test02
network-test03
```

But how to do the same for listing network drivers a container is connected to?

Following is docker inspect,

```
.....
            "Networks": {
                "br01": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {},
                    "Links": null,
                    ........
                },
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    .....
                }
.....
```

I just want to list the Networks like the following,

```
br01
bridge
```

I have tried the following but can't properly work through the template due to my limited knowledge in go templates.

```
docker inspect network-test01 --format "{{.NetworkSettings.Networks}}"
```

Which results the following,

```
map[br01:0xc0000f6180 bridge:0xc0000f6cc0]
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Go or programming question, you might try ServerFault instead.

Comment: Just output the JSON from the `inspect` command to a something like `jq` that has a more flexible  query language?

Comment: @Adrian No, it is not directly a go related questions. But it falls under the domain of `go-template` which I believe is enough reason for being this question to be here. Another thing is if you check I have also added the `docker` tag which seems to be a subjects of Stackoverflow. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @larsk thanks for the suggestion. In that case, I could happily use my favourite tool `awk` and other POSIX parsing tools.

Comment: @xarantolus `Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected ":=" in range`

Comment: How about using `{{range $name, $_ := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{ println $name }}{{end}}` for the format? The output order will be randomized though (if it uses normal Go maps). [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/-3L_0IvvDDj)

Comment: @xarantolus Maps are visited in sorted keys order. Quoting from `text/template`: _"If the value is a map and the keys are of basic type with a defined order, the elements will be visited in sorted key order."_

Comment: @xarantolus you were very close. The second one works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following template will output just the network names:

```
{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{println $k}}{{end}}
```

Example Go code testing it:

```
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "NetworkSettings": map[string]interface{}{
        "Networks": map[string]interface{}{
            "br1":    struct{}{},
            "bridge": struct{}{},
        },
    },
}

t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse("{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{println $k}}{{end}}"))

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oJxYwQvu5T6)):

```
br1
bridge
```

So use the following command:

```
docker inspect network-test01 --format '{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{println $k}}{{end}}'
```

Also note that the `docker` command will also output a newline after each item, so calling `println` can be omitted:

```
docker inspect network-test01 --format '{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{$k}}{{end}}'
```

Comment: Just brilliant! Thanks for the answer. I could use this answer to do different kinds of parsing and stuff.

Comment: My shell complains though `Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected "," in range` with the last docker command you have mentioned. You may add the following cmd which works for me, 
`docker inspect network-test01 --format='{{range $k, $v := .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{$k}}{{end}}'` 
Or replacing the double quote with single works too

Comment: @muhammad Yes, you're right. I haven't actually tried the command, just the template itself.